# Transfer large number of small files from one drive to another in windows

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I have a folder of Geowebcache of Large area have more than 8.5 million tiles how to backup and copy these files from one computer another in an effective and fast way

Answer (score 0):

If your new computer and old computer are both on the same network, you can copy the files to a shared folder (such as the Public folder) on the old computer.